# Need a refresher. Linking with gcc or ln etc on MacOS

Tags: c, linker, shared-libraries

I used to know how to do this but I haven't looked at C/C++ since about 1999. It is just for my own nefarious purposes that I want to create a C library that I can use to demonstrate the Hollywood Principle - don't call us. We'll call you.

I have a main and stubbed out "message(String *arg) function. My goal is to have say an end user implement their version of message(String *arg), link it with my library and then run the resulting executable.

Is it possible for main.o to live in the library too and use the linker to create the exec, overwriting main's link to message and create an executable.

Many years ago, I used to maintain an app that did this but I was only writing TCP/IP stack part of the executable and have forgotten how it was actually pulled off as it was not my primary concern.

Comment: Is your library static or shared? I don't think `main` can be in a shared library. Have you tried doing this? What problem did you encounter? Please show a [mre]

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I tried it with a "shared" library, not a static. I'll give that a try. I'll see what I can do about an example.

Comment: That was it. I read up a little and saw the "ar" command which seemed familiar. It works now. What I like about this is that if one so desired, they could have a main in the static lib that maybe listens for events or polls and then calls the user's function to handle the event.